# Memory use in cuda cusp linear solver

Tags: memory, cuda, out-of-memory, allocation, cusp-library

I am using **cusp::bicgstab** to solve a linear system **Ax=b**, in which **A** is a 3D Poisson on MxNxP mesh, **x** is unknowns, and **b** is the RHS. I have a *K40m Tesla* which has 12GB memory.

I tested with **M=2000, N=2000, P=20** (80 millions unknowns), variable type is **double**; so the total memory used (for **A, x, b,** and others) is approximately **5.5GB**. The code works fine.

Then I increased the value of M or N to 2500 (memory used is still far less than 12GB), the program encountered the following error:

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'thrust::system::detail::bad_alloc'
>
> what():  std::bad_alloc: out of memory
> Aborted (core dumped)

I see that the error is "**out of device memory**". Therefore, I am wondering about the memory management in **cusp** library. Does it use about the same memory space for extra variables (as used for **A,x,b**) during the iterations to solve the system?

Below is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cuda.h>
#include <cuda_runtime_api.h>

#include <cusp/monitor.h>
#include <cusp/krylov/bicgstab.h>
#include <cusp/gallery/poisson.h>
#include <cusp/print.h>

// where to perform the computation
typedef cusp::device_memory MemorySpace;

// which floating point type to use
typedef double ValueType;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    size_t avail, total;                // Available and Total memory count
    int N = 2500, M = 2000, P = 20;     // Dimension
    
    // create a matrix for a 3D Poisson problem on a MxNxP grid
    cusp::dia_matrix<int, ValueType, MemorySpace> A;
    cusp::gallery::poisson7pt(A, N, M, P);

    // allocate storage for solution (x) and right hand side (b)
    cusp::array1d<ValueType, MemorySpace> x(N*M*P, 0.0);
    cusp::array1d<ValueType, MemorySpace> b(N*M*P, 1.0);
    
    // set preconditioner (identity)
    cusp::identity_operator<ValueType, MemorySpace> ID(A.num_rows, A.num_rows);
    
    // Set stopping criteria:
    // ... iteration_limit    = 100
    // ... relative_tolerance = 1e-9
    // ... absolute_tolerance = 0
    cusp::default_monitor <ValueType> monitor(b, 100, 1e-9);

    // solve the linear system A x = b
    cusp::krylov::bicgstab(A, x, b, monitor, ID);

    // Get device memory usage
    cudaMemGetInfo( &avail, &total );
    size_t used = total - avail;
    std::cout << "Device memory used: " << used/(1024.*1024.*1024.) << " Gb " << std::endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read the [source](https://github.com/cusplibrary/cusplibrary/blob/develop/cusp/krylov/detail/bicgstab.inl) for the `bicgstab` solver yourself, but it looks like there are eight temporary arrays, each with the same number of entries as rows in your matrix. If I have read your code correctly, that means that you would need to have at least `8 * N * M * P * sizeof(double)` bytes of free GPU memory on entry to the `bicgstab` call for the solver to run.

Comment: You are right. There are 8 additional, temporary arrays used in `bicgstab`. Poisson 3D problems have 9 arrays (A:7, b:1, x:1), so the peak memory used is about `17 * N * M * P * sizeof(double)`. Now everything is clear.